# paste command shell not joining all lines

Tags: shell

I have a file with contents as shown in multiple lines:

aa 
bb
cc
dd

And I want to merge all lines in a single line using paste command. While Using  "paste -s file" command on the terminal I am getting the output as: aa     dd i.e. only first line and last line is getting printed. I dont know what's going wrong in this paste command.

How to correct this so that I can merge all lines in a single line such that I can get the output on terminal as:  aa bb cc dd ?

Comment: check you file format, maybe it is not unix format.try dos2unix or mac2unix to convert it before run paste command

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get everything on one line wuth spaces by using

```
echo file | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/ $/\n/'
```

You can fix windows files with `tr` too:

echo file | tr -d "\r" | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/ $/\n/'